# Tunnel only specific port over OpenVPN on OpenWRT-Merlin

Tags: openvpn, router, tunneling, openwrt, split-tunnel

My *Asus RT-AC87U* router is running [OpenWRT-Merlin](http://asuswrt.lostrealm.ca/). OpenWRT-Merlin allows you to set up an OpenVPN client and disable NAT so that you have to manually configure the routes for this VPN.

How do I do this using `iptables` or `ip route add`, or something else? I find these commands confusing.

I googled around about this but there's nothing that works in a trial-error-copy-paste way. Most of this talk is about removing the routes to the VPN to begin with, which is not necessary on OpenWRT-Merlin because you have the option to not set up NAT routing.

I have a VPN connection over the `tun11` device. I can either forward local ip addresses to the VPN from within the firmware (WebUI), but it's all or nothing.

How do I make it so that for example, only traffic directed at port 80 goes over VPN, and the rest keeps going to my local ISP?

If I am correct, this would show a different ip when using `http` compared to `https`.